# Adding link annotations to a PDF document

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, annotations

How can I add annotations (in a particular shape) to a PDF?

I want to be able to control:

- the link target
- the color
- the shape of the link annotation
- the location of the link annotation

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library being used in this answer

To showcase this behaviour, this example is going to re-create a shape using "pixel-art".

This array, together with these colors define the shape of super-mario:

```
    m = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0],
        [0, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
    ]
    c = [
        None,
        X11Color("Red"),
        X11Color("Black"),
        X11Color("Tan"),
        X11Color("Blue"),
        X11Color("White"),
    ]
```

To manipulate the PDF, I am going to use [pText](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release).
First we are going to read an existing PDF:

```
    # attempt to read PDF
    doc = None
    with open("boring-input.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        print("\treading (1) ..")
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle)
```

Then we are going to add the annotations, using the array indices as references (and keeping in mind the coordinate system for PDF starts at the bottom left):

```
    # add annotation
    pixel_size = 2
    for i in range(0, len(m)):
        for j in range(0, len(m[i])):
            if m[i][j] == 0:
                continue
            x = pixel_size * j
            y = pixel_size * (len(m) - i)
            doc.get_page(0).append_link_annotation(
                page=Decimal(0),
                color=c[m[i][j]],
                location_on_page="Fit",
                rectangle=(
                    Decimal(x),
                    Decimal(y),
                    Decimal(x + pixel_size),
                    Decimal(y + pixel_size),
                ),
            )
```

Then we store the output PDF:

```
    # attempt to store PDF
    with open("its-a-me.pdf, "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, doc)
```

This is a screenshot of Okular opening the PDF:

[image]

Comment: This one needs a disclaimer too. They all do